# Validation Method that Returns Boolean Based off User Input

Tags: vb.net

Right now I am setting a message for each specific user input then displaying them into a Result Label. The function needs to return a boolean. I am stuck trying to clean up my if statements.. trying to find a cleaner logical approach to this Validation function. As of right now this is what I have.

```
    Private Function UserInputValidation() As Boolean

    Dim isValid As Boolean = True
    Dim inputError As String = String.Empty
    Dim price As Double

    If cmbMake.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        inputError += "" & vbCrLf
    End If

    If txtModel.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
        inputError += "" & vbCrLf
    End If

    If cmbYear.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        inputError += "" & vbCrLf
    End If

    If txtPrice.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
        inputError += "" & vbCrLf
    Else
        If Double.TryParse(txtPrice.Text.Trim, price) = False OrElse price < 0.0 Then
            txtPrice.Clear()
            inputError += ""
        End If
    End If

    If inputError <> String.Empty Then
        isValid = False
        lblError.Text = inputError
    End If

    Return isValid

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first thing, use `&=` to concatenate strings instead of `+=`. Both forms do work, but there are advantages to `&=` while `+=` has no advantages and may let you crash your own application.

If you want to really hit it out of the ballpark, use a StringBuilder. There are no big difference for you as a programmer, but your machine will use slightly less ressources.

Now, the way you write your statements can let unused empty lines at the end of a statement. You can deal with this by writing them like this (assuming you are using a `System.Text.StringBuilder`):

```
    Dim inputError As System.Text.StringBuilder
    If TestForSomething Then
        inputError.AppendLine("This is an error message")
    End If
```

And then at the end you can write:

```
    If inputError.Trim.Length > 0 Then
        lblError.Text = inputError.ToString
    End If

    Return inputError.ToString = "" 'you don't really need the isValid variable
```

Validating `txtPrice` could be cleaner, but I'm unsure if you have different error messages for every possibility or if you'll just use a general "Price is wrong" message, so I won't go into details.

What you're doing seems to be all right. There's not a billion ways to do what you're doing, and you got the right idea. The rest is nitpicking, like I would suggest to compare your strings to `""` instead of checking for Length... but both works.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you use the validation functionality built into WinForms. You should handle the `Validating` event of each control and validate just that control there. If you want to validate multiple controls in the same way then use a common event handler and use the `sender` to determine which control it is. You can call `ValidateChildren` on the form to validate all controls, even if they haven't received focus.  E.g.

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

    Private ReadOnly errorMessagesByControl As New Dictionary(Of Control, String)

    Private Sub NumericTextBoxes_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating, TextBox2.Validating
        Dim control = DirectCast(sender, Control)

        'Check that the field contains a number.
        If Double.TryParse(control.Text, Nothing) Then
            'Remove existing error message on successful validation.
            errorMessagesByControl.Remove(control)
        ElseIf Not errorMessagesByControl.ContainsKey(control) Then
            'Add error message if one does not already exist.
            errorMessagesByControl.Add(control, $"Please enter a number in the {control.Tag} field.")
        End If

        DisplayErrorMessages()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.Validating
        If TextBox3.TextLength = 0 Then
            errorMessagesByControl.Add(TextBox3, $"Please enter some text in the {TextBox3.Tag} field.")
        ElseIf Not errorMessagesByControl.ContainsKey(TextBox3) Then
            errorMessagesByControl.Remove(TextBox3)
        End If

        DisplayErrorMessages()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayErrorMessages()
        Label1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, errorMessagesByControl.Values)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If ValidateChildren() Then
            'All fields passed validation so use the data with confidence.
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

This assumes that each control has its `Tag` populated with the field name to be displayed in the error messages. All current error messages are stored in a `Dictionary` so they can be added and removed with ease. The error messages are combined and displayed each and every time validation occurs.

You might also consider using a `ErrorProvider` to display errors against individual controls rather than using a single `Label`.